# What is the difference between the first two sentences and the third sentence that makes the third sentence an argument but the not the first two?

Tags: logic

The ones that aren't arguments:
"Her favorite color is yellow because it is the color of the sun." (*Critical Thinking)*
"Pooh is my favorite cartoon character because he has lots of personality." (*Critical Thinking*)

The one that is an argument:
"American Idol is history, but when you remember whose careers were launched by AI, you known it was the best talent show on TV." (*Critical Thinking*)

Comment: All of them can be made into logical arguments if you add some supplementary premises, say "if a cartoon character has lots of personality, that character will be my favorite" or "the best talent show on TV is the one that launches the careers of the most artists with best-selling albums". None of them are logically valid arguments as stated, without additional premises they are all non sequiturs.

Comment: In the book, it says that the third sentence is an argument while the first two are claims.